# C# variables, methods, reference exercise

Tags: c#

I have made an exercise on C#, here it is:

```
class Program
{
    static double funk(int a, ref int b)
    {
        double c = a + b;
        a = 5;
        b = a * 3;
        return c;
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(funk(a, ref b));
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So, the result is pretty clear when I run the code, it gives me:

```
3
1
15
```

My question now is, where did 15 and 3 came from?

Comment: Debug the program and look at each line, step by step, to see what happens.  If you have a specific question about a specific line, rather than just asking for us to explain the entire program (and try to guess at which parts you do and don't understand) then the question will be more appropriate for the site.

Comment: First WriteLine is printing `c` which is returned from `funk()` which is `a + b`.  The third WriteLine is printing the value of `b` which was changed since the `ref` keyword passes it to the function by reference (changes occur in the caller as well).

Answer (score 6):

The 3 came from:

```
double c = a + b;

//...
return c;
```

This gets printed out to the `Console` via the first `WriteLine`.

The 15 comes from:

```
double c = a + b; // c == 3
a = 5;
b = a * 3; // b == 5 * 3 == 15
```

Since you pass in `b` with `ref`, you're changing the actual value of the caller variable (`b` in `Main`), which gets set to 15, then printed out by the third `WriteLine`.

Answer (score 2):

For the variable  b you pass a a reference to its memory location. In this way, changing that variable inside the function `funk` changes the value in the same memory location of the variable b declared in Main. The remaining values are simpler.

You have

```
3    as the result of the call to funk(a, ref b) 
1    as the original value of a (not changed inside funk)
15   as the result of the a*3 assigned to the address of b inside funk
```

Answer (score 0):

- 3 is the result of funk(a, ref b), c is returned and it equals 3.
- 15 is the new value of b, inside of funk b = a * 3, the local value of a inside of funk was set to 5, b = 5 * 3
- - because b is passed as a ref[erence] parameter of funk it's value can be altered inside of funk

Answer (score 0):

3 is the returned C, which is the sum of the 2 variables passed into the function.

the 1 is a's initialized value, since the function does not return or change a in the scope of the console.writeline.

the 15 is the modified b, since it was passed into the other function as a reference changes made to it in that function also apply to the variable that was passed.